# Itunes Verify Receipt SSL certificate error

Tags: php, ios, curl, in-app-purchase, ssl-certificate

I having trouble with verify receipt from ios in-app purchase in production environnement (https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt)

it seems that my server dosen't have the good certificate.

```
$ch = curl_init("https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

this code throw an exception :

```
SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. 
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

i've tried to manually set cert from http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

```
$ch = curl_init($endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO,'/var/cert/ca-bundle.crt');
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

but that does not change.

Do you have an idea to fix this? thanks